# How to specify a standard path (location) for stylesheets

Tags: css, path, hyperlink

Is there a way to specify a standard path for stylesheets (analogous to the "include_path" directive in the php.ini file that specifies the location of PHP includes files) such that you only need to specify the unqualified stylesheet filename in the href value of the link element? Example, just be able to write:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
```

in all files, regardless of their location on the website, without having to worry about where the main.css file is located?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start your path with a `/` and it will be interpreted relative to the root of your website and will work on any file regardless of its location:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/main.css" />
```

or if main.css is not in root:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/some_folder/main.css" />
```

Comment: I've seen this solution in research I did before asking here. It didn't work on my local server (XAMPP on Windows). Does this solution assume a *nix server? If so, what if I wanted to maintain a local version on my Windows machine in addition to a live version on a webhost?

Comment: @AlienWebguy: Yeah but I tried this on my local machine and it didn't work.

Comment: I use XAMPP every day - it'll work :)  If your css files are in a css folder in root, you'd use `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/whatever.css" />`

Comment: That doesn't have to do with the OS on the webserver. A slash `/` just indicates the web-root. If your webpages are in e.g. `C:\htdocs\index.htm` and `C:\htdocs\category\subpage.htm`, your main.css should be located at `C:\htdocs\main.css`.

Comment: Yes, you guys are right -- it does work. I forgot that my stylesheet directory wasn't directly webroot -- it was in a project subdirectory. Thanks very much!

Comment: @Bill Actually this doesn't have anything to do with the server, it is a browser thing, when the browser sees `href="/main.css"` makes a request for `/main.css` to the server and if the file is accessible there this should work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Use the HTML-base-tag:

```
<base href="http://your.domain/and/path/here/" />
```

Now, **all** your links will start at that position, even URL's inside a `<LINK>`.

Comment: I suppose this would work, but it would require a fair bit of extra coding, putting a base element in every page. Plus, dedicating base for this purpose would prevent using it for creating a base URL for page (body) links. Thank you.